# Letsencrypt Acme Companion + Local Subdomain

Tags: letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion

I'm trying to set up self-signed cert to get HTTPS for a local development domain. I use subdomains of our real domain for local development. Example:

`local-www.someapp.com`

Where `local-www.someapp.com` is set to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file. (I do own the domain and have access to Route53 so I can set records, etc.)

Then, I use a Docker jwilder/nginx-proxy container. I want to install the acme-companion container to generate a self-signed SSL cert just for this local subdomain to enable HTTPS for local development. When I set it up, I set the `LETSENCRYPT_HOST` to `local-www.someapp.com`, but this subdomain is not publicly available otherwise.

Is it possible to succeed the DNS challenge in this scenario with Route53? I seem to have hit my rate limit with LE on the `local-www.someapp.com` domain now anyway, so I may need to wait it out or find another name to attempt to generate with.

I'd also like to be able to share this SSL cert with another developer in the future. Is this the wrong way to go about this?

I attempted to set the `LETSENCRYPT_HOST` on the proxied container to `local-www.someapp.com` but it failed with an NXDOMAIN no such name found (A or AAAA). I can't retrieve the error from the container and now I've hit the rate limits. I think I am barking up the wrong tree with the local subdomain, since it must be publicly accessible.

Comment: "I attempted to set the LETSENCRYPT_HOST on the proxied container to local-www.someapp.com but it failed with an NXDOMAIN no such name found (A or AAAA)." Could you specify what process failed and gave you this message. The command or the steps taken to set the LETSENCRYPT_HOST on the proxied container would help us better understand your situation :)